# can't find what I want in logminer, in fact, can't find anything recent

Tags: oracle

I am the sysadmin for a school, so I'm an IT generalist, jack of all trades, master of none, right?  Our student information system runs on top of Oracle 11g.  Would like to know how to use logminer to find out, at the very least, when something was changed in the database that shouldn't have been changed.

I have configured a test server to play with, so rest your mind, our production system isn't at risk while I play here.

The server is Windows. I go to a command prompt, type sqlplus / as sysdba.

Execute `dbms.logmnr.addlogfile` blah, blah multiple times to add the log files.

alter session set `NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'mm-dd-yyyy HH24:mi:ss';` so the time stamps tell me more than just the date.

Then I go to the application on my test server and make a change to a student demographic record.  I want to find this change using logminer.

I do a `select timestamp,sql_undo from V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS WHERE  TIMESTAMP > TO_DATE('04-11-2013 11:59:00');`  (I made the change just now, around 3 pm)

I get no rows.

If I do the same thing, but with a time just after midnight, I get thousands of rows, as the app has routines that kick off at midnight doing maintenance, like recalculating student's class ranks, for instance.

So why am I not finding the change I made logged? I  believe I'm looking in the right log files, or I wouldn't see the activity at midnight.

Comment: i think what you are looking for is `AUDIT`. `AUDIT` enables you to track specific user activity , DML + DDL, on a specific schema/object + fine grained auditing etc ... log miner is usually used once all other options are exhausted. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Though your latest entry is recorded it won't appear in V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS till it has sufficient number of updates recorded. For example, if you do 100 updates, you may get 80. To flush out the remaining 20, you need to have some more updates done so that you can see them again. We had a similar problem where logminer was particularly not showing latest updates especially if they are very few. We had to create a dummy table to create some updates regularly so that logminer is always actively showing the updates and nothing is stored in buffer. In our usecase creating the dummy table was ok, I am not sure if it's ok in your case.